# Best practice instance objects - dictionary vs object

Tags: json, performance, dictionary, object, render

let's say I have a complexe object with hundrets of properties.
Is there a real downside using dictionaries instead of hierarchical objects?

In the past I used objects with complexe structure, but I am not sure any longer, whether I should use them in the future.

With dictionaries, I am flexible and can return only the needed data, but the downside will be the performance - at least that is, what I am thinking and the readability of the code of course.

On the other hand, with objects, I think it will be faster, but I always get data which I do not really need.

Here are two examples of my problem. Maybe someone can give me an opinion, whether I should use dictionaries or objects. This is just an example, in real world, the article object will have way over hundert of properties and several sub classes.

```
    // Dictonary class
    class ArticleDictionary {
      public int Id { get; set; }
      public Dictionary<string, object> Infos = new();
      public Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, object>> SellingInfos = new();
      public Dictionary<string, object> DetailInfos = new();
      public Dictionary<string, object> DispatchInfos = new();
    }

    // Object classes
    class ArticleProperty {
      public int Id { get; set; }
      public string Model { get; set; }
      public string EanNumber { get; set; }
      public string CreationDate { get; set; }
      public string Description { get; set; }
      public int State { get; set; }
    }

    class ArticleDetailProperty : ArticleProperty {
      public string TechnicalData { get; set; }
      public string Features { get; set; }
      public Dictionary<string, ArticleSellingInfosProperty> SellingInfos = new();
    }

    class ArticleMoreDetailProperty : ArticleDetailProperty {
      public string DispatchInfos { get; set; }
    }

    class ArticleSellingInfosProperty {
      public string WarehouseKey { get; set; }
      public Decimal PriceA { get; set; }
      public Decimal PriceB { get; set; }
      public int Stock { get; set; }
    }
```